# How do I create a dot prefixed cookie uri?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, uri

I am trying to pass a Uri of `new Uri(".example.com")`

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

or `new Uri("http://.example.com")`

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

I need to be able to use the `CookieContainer.SetCookies` function which only has one overload taking a Uri.

According to [this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/478521/cookiecontainer-domain-handling-issue), .NET 4.0 should support dot prefixed cookies now, but it seems the Uri class does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to pass a proper uri to the function, and the Uri parser is correctly rejecting the malformed string you are trying to use.

I would advise using the [Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a18ka3h2.aspx) Constructor that takes 4 parameters - allowing you to set the domain to a dot-prefixed one.

```
Cookie(string name, string value, string path, string domain);
```

Comment: This seemed like the only work around that was available.  Unfortunately it will be alot of refactoring to change all the places Uri's are used.  Came here hoping maybe there was another way to indicate the . prefixed URI.  You said that my string is malformed?  How is my string malformed?  RFC standard states a domain with a . prefix is valid for a cookie.

Comment: It's malformed when passed in as a `Uri()` - they have different requirements

Comment: What about when using `GetCookies()`?